# How to rename columns in select union queries?

Tags: mysql

Hello I have the following query where I want to select the client from the clients table and the values statuses and currencies from the settings table. I made this query but is not working for the reason that both tables, client's and settings' have a column with the name id.

```
SELECT *, clients.id as client_id FROM clients_table as clients WHERE clients.id = 163
UNION SELECT settings.values AS statuses FROM settings_table as settings WHERE settings.options = 'statuses'
UNION SELECT setting.il_values AS currencies FROM settings_table as setting WHERE setting.options = 'currencies'
```

The error message that I'm getting

> #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

How I can fix it?

Comment: It's not failing because both tables have a column with the name id, but because your `select` statements have different numbers of columns, as the error clearly says.  The first `select` has n+1 columns, where n is the number of columns in `clients_table`, the next 2 `select` statements have only 1 column.

Comment: UNION queries have to have the same number of columns in each `SELECT`.  You could add the correct number of `NULL` columns to your `SELECT` statements (e.g. `SELECT settings.values AS statuses, NULL, NULL, ...`, but without knowing what you're trying to achieve, I don't know whether this is a good idea or not.

Comment: basically I want to collect the client with the given id and the values from the settings table for both values statuses and currencies performing one query

Comment: You can fix it by separating the queries. You are now requesting two completely different objects. Why? You're not saving time (rather the contrary), and the code is far less maintainable. Change the *clients* table and you wreck a *settings* query. I suspect you've run into the XY problem: *that* is what you really need to fix: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it -- but it would be better to separate the queries.

```
 SELECT *, clients.id as client_id FROM clients_table ...
 UNION SELECT settings.values, NULL, NULL, NULL... AS statuses 
 SELECT setting.il_values, NULL, NULL, NULL... AS currencies ...
```

You add as many NULL columns as are needed to make the SELECTs have the same number of rows. Then you will get:

```
 User    Email    Password    id
 john    ...      ...         613
 active  NULL     NULL        NULL
 dollar  NULL     NULL        NULL
```

You clearly want to retrieve both *settings* and *currencies* and distinguish them, but since you run **one** select, any column will only have **one** name. So the first column will be either called "User" or "setting" or "currency", but never *the right value".

If you want to collect all information in one fell swoop, you need to renounce the "*" syntax and do something like:

```
SELECT 'userinfo' as wtf, User, Name, Email, ... FROM customers
UNION
SELECT 'setting' as wtf, value, keyname, null, ... FROM settings
UNION
SELECT 'currency' as wtf, value, null, null, ... FROM currencies
```

and this will give you:

```
wtf         User     Password
userinfo    John     whatever ...
setting     800x600  resolution     NULL
setting     Mozilla  browser        NULL
currency    dollar   NULL           NULL
```

which will allow you to tell which is which.

Even so, you won't be able to mix reliably data types (depends on your app DA layer). So if you have a "exchange_rate" column in currencies that's a NUMERIC, and it corresponds to a User column of "Password", anything may happen. Usually, Murphy being Murphy, something you wouldn't want to.

To avoid this, if it becomes a problem, you need to add an extra column of the appropriate type in all the tables that haven't it, and give it an appropriate value (NULL, or 0.0, or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

`union` operation need same number of columns for every query. So you must `select` the same number of columns from `clients_table`, `settings_table`.

Comment: so that it means that the settings table has 3 columns and the client has 6 columns is not going to work?

Comment: You can make it work by fetching some extra columns from setting table(like some count) or fetching 3 columns from client. But its upto you.